# How do you change the background image of a website with a click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning on how to use buttons and for my website I would like to be able to click a button and the websites background image will change. I am using JavaScript and the button tag for this. Please help me out with my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
        <title> Test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="changeBackground" onclick="changebgImage()">Change Background</button>
        <script>
function changebgImage() {
    document.body.style.background-image = url(Paradise.jpg);
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage= "url('img_tree.png')";
```

not `background-image`

And you **MUST** encapsulate strings in quotes.

Comment: Thank you, Seems like I was missing a few things and instead of Javascript syntax used CSS.

Comment: If you're satisfied with my answer, tick the answer on the left to accept it :). You're welcome.

Comment: I have to wait nine minutes, I will :)

Comment: Ref http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp :)